# How to select the most important features to use in forecasting Neural Network Model?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, predictive-models, feature-selection

I have a data collection contains many variables as inputs and the output is the daily cash demand in an ATM.
How can i select the most important variables which have the most influence on the output (Demand) to to use in my forecasting Model based on Neural Network?
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on 
a) what input variables you have access to?
b) What output you want to measure ? (frequency, amount of money,..)

But given thats its amount of money,I'd start with: days since payday or 1st of the month, weekday, time of day,  frequency of withdrawals